# Can we use phonegap/Ionic hybride app for mobile website

Tags: ionic-framework, phonegap

Does phonegap or Ionic framework can be used for mobile website.

Actually I am planing to build mobile app. But confused to pick one of them (phonegap/Ionic).

So, please guide me which one is better. And please guide which one is best for both mobile app and mobile website.

Comment: phonegap is old, ionic framework in new, and it is updating day by day. so better to use ionic.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, But my primary concern is that I want same code for web and app both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first Phonegap is now called Cordova.

Cordova builds an native App using HTML, Javascript and CSS.

With the ionic framework you can Create and Design "Apps" with HTML, Typescript and Sass. Ionic is perfect if you want your App our mobile website to look like an normal native App. Ionic uses Cordova to build the App. I used Ionic myself to build a website.

Ionic gives you the option to build for a browser (ionic build browser). 
Then you get the computed HTML, Javascript and CSS.

Please excuse my English, i´m from Germany ;)

Comment: Thanks, Ionic sounds good. One of my friend is suggesting me about **React Native**. What is your opinion on that.

Comment: I`ve never tryed React Native but it looks quite similar to Ionic. Ionic features alot of nice components with good examples and live demo on the website. I think Ionic is the solution if you want your app/website to look like a normal iOS or Android App but it´s also very customizable. I love ionic´s nice Documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks for your review.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. In ionic2 you can do

```
ionic platform add browser
ionic build browser
```

Example of website using ionic http://m.stubapp.com/